# Class read error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let buttonsend = document.querySelector(".button");

function buttonSendnotavailable() {
  buttonsend.classList.remove("button");
  buttonsend.classList.add("disabledButtonsend");
  buttonsend = false;
}

function buttonSendavailable() {
  buttonsend.classList.remove("disabledButtonsend");
  buttonsend.classList.add("button");
  buttonsend = true;
}

function() {
  buttonSendnotavailable();
  buttonSendavailable();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="button"> </input>
```

Why when I want to change the classes depending on the function and the variable that finds the button is global, I get an error in the title? Only the code I provided is responsible for what I want to get?
There was already a similar question to the one I asked, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: The last function doesn't have a name

Comment: I edited .. Run the snippet .. It tells you what your syntax error is.

Comment: Okay, but it won't change anything.

Comment: Apart from the above syntax error, you are overriding the buttonsend variable and change its type to boolean. Not sure what are you trying to achieve!

Comment: I know that, I wanted the button to be unavailable. I didn't think it had much effect on the value of the variable.

Comment: Even if I remove the false and true value assignment of the button, the error doesn't go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your approach .. The single largest is that you are defining `buttonsend` using a class selector that you then later remove, so it is no longer "available" to the DOM.

The resulting error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')"` occurs because at this point the class `button` is no longer assigned to your element (which you are using as your selector)

I simply changed the selector, and kept the "button" class.  A working proof of concept is in the snip below:

```js
let buttonsend = document.querySelector(".my_button");

function buttonSendnotavailable() {
  buttonsend.classList.remove("button");
  buttonsend.classList.add("disabledButtonsend");
}

function buttonSendavailable() {
  buttonsend.classList.remove("disabledButtonsend");
  buttonsend.classList.add("button");
}
```

```css
 input{
  display: none;
}

.button{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="my_button button" />

<button onClick="buttonSendavailable()">
Enable
</button>

<button onClick="buttonSendnotavailable()">
Disable
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added 1 constant class to this button, now everything works.

Comment: Glad to help ..  Mark question as accepted if this resolved your OP